# Series resistor on VFB of LTC3652 solar charger

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I use a [LTC3652 solar charger](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3652fe.pdf) from a given [schematic](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Prototyping/SunnyBuddy-v13a.pdf) for a solar powered microcontroller board and I want to understand the circuit a little bit more.

So why do they connect a resistor (`R6`) in series with the `VFB` pin of the regulator? I read the description of the `VFB` input and they write that the output voltage is only regulated with the voltage divider. So what is the function of `R6`?

Comment: read the datasheet page 15  (pdf page 16)

Comment: Ahh great. Thank you.